# Send image attachment using phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

1. i'm using this code to upload and attach an image through a form, and send it to a mail (as html not as smtp).
   once i enter this (the code) page in the web, i can see the output just fine, i can click the "choose file" and choose a file from some directory.
   but, i can see as well right away when enterind the page the echo "invalid file" probably because an image didn't upload yet by me, but the code runs and not waiting for me to choose something.
   am i missing some triger that will submit my choise and than send it?
2. when configuring it to be sent as an html like i did, does $mail->Send() is enough and when the code reaches to that command the mail with the attach will be sent?? or i need some other triger to send it?

thank you,

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");
// Process
$action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
if (empty($action)) 
{
    $output = "<form action='#'>
               <h1>header: </h1>
                <label for='image'>upload:  </label>
                <input type='file' id='image' name='image' maxlength=50 >";

}
echo $output;
$image = $_POST["image"];
uploadImage($image);
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$Email_to = "some@gmail.com"; // the one that recieves the email
$email_from = "someone@someone.net";
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
chmod("uploads",0777);

function uploadImage($image){
    if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 2097152)
    && (strlen($_FILES["image"]["name"]) < 51)){
        if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"];
            }
        else{
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br />";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br />";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

                if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }
                else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                        "images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            }
            }
    }else{
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $dir = "uploads/$filename";
    chmod("uploads",0777);
    $success = copy($_FILES[images][tmp_name], $dir);
    if ($success) {
    echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
    SendIt();
    }
}

function SendIt() {
//
global $attachments,$Email_to,$Email_msg,$email_subject,$email_from;
//
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//$mail->IsSMTP();// send via SMTP
//$mail->Host = "localhost"; // SMTP servers
//$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // turn on/off SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;// set word wrap
//now Attach all files submitted
$mail->AddAttachment("uploads"."/".$_FILES["image"]["type"]);
//
$mail->IsHTML(true);// send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be firing the uploadImage function when there IS an $action:

```
...previous code...
if (empty($action)) 
{
?>
<form action=''>
    <h1>header: </h1>
    <label for='image'>upload:  </label>
    <input type='file' id='image' name='image' maxlength=50 >
</form>
<?php
    exit; // stop the upload script running
}

$image = $_POST["image"];
uploadImage($image);
require("class.phpmailer.php");
... rest of the code ...
```